# Embedding custom platforms to YouTrack KB articles

Tags: embedding, youtrack, draw.io, diagrams.net

YouTrack Knowledge base out of the box supports embedding only of a [*few external sources*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/embedding-content.html). Content from these external sources are rendered as `<iframes>`. Content from all other external sources URLs is rendered as `<img>`.

Is it possible to configure a local instance of YouTrack running in Docker to support rendering custom external sources as `<iframe>`?

I need this for embedding drawings made on a local instance of [*diagrams.net*](https://diagrams.net) (*draw.io*), which is also running locally as a Docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we can't allow *any* sources to be displayed in  by default, we decided to create a feature request (based on your input) for a setting with a list of custom domains that would be allowed as iframes: [JT-78713](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-78713/Specifying-custom-iframe-allowed-sources). Feel free to vote for it, as it helps us gauge which features are in demand.

As a workaround, you could implement a custom DNS setup locally to point one of the domains that are already allowed (e.g., diagrams.net) to the custom resource that you need embedded as an iframe in the KB articles.